# iphone objective-c programmatically creating labels

Tags: ios, iphone, alignment

I am creating the label programmatically with dynamic text, and next to label one more textview is present which is dynamic content, and next to text view there is an imageview.  These three are not aligning correctly,

```
_textView = [[[JSTwitterCoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,60,self.view.frame.size.width,130)] autorelease];
_textView.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
_textView.linkColor=[UIColor lightTextColor];
[self.view addSubview:_textView];
CGFloat Lsize=_textView.bounds.size.height+_textView.bounds.origin.y;
//CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 50;
//CGFloat height = [self textHeight:text] + 10;
//CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, width, height);
startLine=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,Lsize, 320, 2)];
[self.view addSubview:startLine];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the `UITextView` and `UIImageView` also programmatically? If that is the case you just need to set their frame's 'x' or 'y' (depending on horizontal or vertical alignment) to the same value, like this:

```
// Vertical alignment
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:           CGRectMake(labelX, y, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:      CGRectMake(textX, y, textWidth, textHeight)];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:   CGRectMake(imageX, y, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with calling sizeToFit on UILabel objects then positioning the labels. First setup the label with the appropriate content and other settings, then call sizeToFit, then move them to the appropriate places. For example I use this code to size and align two labels:

```
[countDescriptorLabel sizeToFit];
[countOutputLabel sizeToFit];
    [countOutputLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(countDescriptorLabel.frame.origin.x + countDescriptorLabel.frame.size.width, countOutputLabel.frame.origin.y, countOutputLabel.frame.size.width, countOutputLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

Depending upon the content, I'll frequently have a space as the last character in the first label's text to make spacing work right.